# Spark map-side aggregation: Per partition only?

Tags: apache-spark

I have been reading on map-side reduce/aggregation and there is one thing I can't seem to understand clearly. Does it happen per partition only or is it broader in scope? I mean does it also reduce across partitions if the same key appears in multiple partitions processed by the same Executor?

Now I have a few more questions depending on whether the answer is "per partition only" or not.

Assuming it's per partition:

- What are good ways to deal with a situation where I know my dataset lends itself well to reducing further across local partitions before a shuffle. E.g. I process 10 partitions per Executor and I know they all include many overlapping keys, so it could potentially be reduced to just 1/10th. Basically I'm looking for a local reduce() (like so many). Coalesce()ing them comes to mind, any common methods to deal with this?

Assuming it reduces across partitions:

- Does it happen per Executor? How about Executors assigned to the same Worker node, do they have the ability to reduce across each others partitions recognizing that they are co-located?
- Does it happen per core (Thread) within the Executor? The reason I'm asking this is because some of the diagrams I looked at seem to show a Mapper per core/Thread of the executor, it looks like results of all tasks coming out of that core goes to a single Mapper instance. (which does the shuffle writes if I am not mistaken)
- Is it deterministic? E.g. if I have a record, let's say A=1 in 10 partitions processed by the same Executor, can I expect to see A=10 for the task reading the shuffle output? Or is it best-effort, e.g. it still reduces but there are some constraints (buffer size etc.) so the shuffle read may encounter A=4 and A=6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map side aggregation is similar to Hadoop `combiner` approach. Reduce locally makes sense to Spark as well and means less shuffling. So it works per partition - as you state.

When applying reducing functionality, e.g. a groupBy & sum, then shuffling occurs initially so that keys are in same partition, so that the above can occur (with dataframes automatically). But a simple count, say, will also reduce locally and then the overall count will be computed by taking the intermediate results back to the driver.

So, results are combined on the Driver from Executors - depending on what is actually requested, e.g. collect, print of a count. But if writing out after aggregation of some nature, then the reducing is limited to the Executor on a Worker.

Comment: Thanks, I waited a bit to see if there would be more answers. Unfortunately, If I am not missing something and unless the phrase "it works per partition" means "It ONLY works per parititon, period", this is still somewhat vague to me. Let me simplify further, I have rdd.mapPartitions().reduceByKey(), mapPartitions() output is A=1 and A=2, for 2 separate partitions (on the same Executor) before reduce - shuffle. Can map-side reduce be applied across these 2 different partitions, resulting potentially A=3 to be written for shuffle, or is it not applied across partitions at all?

Comment: The concept is PER PARTITION. it does not matter if partitions on same worker or serviced by same executor.  Final AGGRegation is then over all those partitions. Answer is correct.